# RPX openID auth_info in java

Tags: authentication, jsp, openid, rpx

I am using RPXnow Openid service with java but I am not getting how to call authentication url of api with token and obtain xml response returned by openid service in same calling jsp.Pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chava,

You use the "token" parameter POSTed to your token_url after RPX processes the authentication.  Use the token to make a back channel API call from your servlet to the RPX service and get the authentication info response in XML.  See https://rpxnow.com/docs for more information about the workflow and API.

Cheers,
Brian